# What is the difference between $_. and $_

Tags: powershell

Not a programmer nor script guy, but I'm quickly getting up to speed with Powershell and love it.  That said, what is the difference when you say

```
$_.(something) and    
$_ (something)
```

Comment: Do you have a real life example of a statement looking like `$_ (something)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_` is a variable that represents/references some object.

The dot notation means you're referencing a specific *member* of the object (a property or method).

Using `$_` alone references the whole object.

So for example, if you had:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows | ForEach-Object {
    $_  # this references the entire object returned.

    $_.FullName  # this refers specifically to the FullName property
}
```